# How to make auto folding code in react-ace editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs

everyone. I have, for example, this JSON and I need to from the start fold fields in the **react-ace** editor. How can I do it from code?

It's what I have at this moment:

[image]

It's what I need to do from code:

[image]

I suppose that vanilla Ace editor has options for this but I can't find them in the version for React.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can acces foldAll () and unfold () through reference

```
(aceEditorReference.current.editor.session.foldAll(1,aceEditorReferenca.current.editor.session.doc.getAllLines().length or  aceEditorReference.current.editor.session.unfold())
```